# Unity WebGL SendMessage to Unity function error object InGameCanvas/CoilValue not found

Tags: javascript, html, unity-game-engine, sendmessage, unity-webgl

I've been trying to send a message from a web page using JavaScript to a Unity function but I continue to get a value not found when calling the function.  *The object associated is a child object of the canvas so Im not sure that's an issue or not.*    Ive tried a combination of things to make it

coilScore is a float and I'm simply passing the number across.

**My attempts to reach child object.**

```
gameInstance.SendMessage('CoilValue', 'ReceiveCoilScore', coilScore);[![enter image description here][1]][1]
gameInstance.SendMessage('InGameCanvas/CoilValue', 'ReceiveCoilScore', coilScore);
gameInstance.SendMessage('InGameCanvas', 'ReceiveCoilScore', coilScore);
gameInstance.SendMessage('InGameCanvas.CoilValue', 'ReceiveCoilScore', coilScore);


Error: 
SendMessage: object InGameCanvas/CoilValue not found!  a4527c6b-a81a-4c23-8861-f3553ac675c8:8:48803
Type: number Total coilScore: 0.000001401 meta_monetization_handler.js:34:10
```

[image: JavaScript snippet to call Unity function]
[image: Unity Function]
[image: Game Object Structure]

**EDIT**

Ive added additional information below this line for clarity.

The index.html is calling a .js file.  Inside that .js file I am parsing multiple parameters but the one item I am trying to do is send a message from the .js file to Unity.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Moon Run</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="TemplateData/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
    <script src="TemplateData/UnityProgress.javascript"></script>
    <script src="Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
        var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/Moon Run WebGL nonDev.json", {onProgress: UnityProgress});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="webgl-content">
    <div id="gameContainer" style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px"></div>
</div>
<script src="TemplateData/responsive.javascript"></script>
<script src="meta_monetization_handler.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**meta_monetization_handler.js**

```
   function calcValue(data) {
    return (data.amount * (1 / Math.pow(10, data.assetScale)).toPrecision(data.assetScale)).toPrecision(data.assetScale);
}

if (typeof document.monetization == "undefined") {
    console.log('document.monetization not found :(');
} else {
    var info_div = document.querySelector('body > div > div.validator > div');
    var ilp_element = document.getElementById('ilpEnabled');
    var ilp_raw_init_el = document.getElementById('rawInit');
    var cur_pay_el = document.getElementById('currentPaymentAmt');
    var total_estimate_el = document.getElementById('totalEstimateAmt');
    var latest_json_el = document.getElementById('latestJson');

    document.monetization.addEventListener('monetizationstart', function(event) {
        info_div.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(63, 65, 68, 0.4)";
        ilp_element.innerHTML = "Interledger Enabled! (Meta-Tag)<br><br>:)  Thank You!<br>";
        ilp_raw_init_el.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(event.detail, null, 2).replace('{','').replace('}','');
    });

    document.monetization.addEventListener('monetizationprogress', function(event) {
        if (typeof this.runningTotal == "undefined") {
            this.runningTotal = 0;
        }
        var monetizationAmount = parseFloat(calcValue(event.detail));
        this.runningTotal += monetizationAmount;
        document.monetization.lastEventPayload = event.detail;
        cur_pay_el.innerHTML = "Latest ILP Payment: $" + monetizationAmount;
        total_estimate_el.innerHTML = "Estimated ILP Total: $" + this.runningTotal.toPrecision(4);
        latest_json_el.innerHTML = "Latest ILP Payment Response: " + JSON.stringify(event.detail);

    coilScore = this.runningTotal.toPrecision(4);
    console.log("Type: " + typeof coilScore  + " Total coilScore: " + coilScore );
    gameInstance.SendMessage('CoilValueTextObject', 'ReceiveCoilScore', coilScore);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the canvas to match the camera view. I also noticed much later that javascript was using toPrecision(4) and I had a function that wa taking a float.
toPrecision was conerting the float to a string and string to use that as an argument hence it failed.

**Solution : Ensure that what I have been sending was a string and the function on the receiving end takes a string.**

```
    public void ReceiveCoilScore(float newValue)
    {
        //gameSession.coilScore = newValue;
        //coilScoreText.text = string.Format("{0:N9}", gameSession.GetCoilScore());
        coilScore = newValue;
        coilScoreText.text = string.Format("{0:N9}", coilScore);
    }
```

**Converting float to string**

```
    coilScore = this.runningTotal.toPrecision(4);
    console.log("Type: " + typeof coilScore  + " Total coilScore: " + coilScore );
    gameInstance.SendMessage('CoilValueTextObject', 'ReceiveCoilScore', coilScore);
```

[image: Canvas matches Camera]

Answer (score 0):

Let's call unity from a unity javascript library file.

First things first, remove this line `<script src="meta_monetization_handler.js"></script>` from the bottom of your index.html.

Now lets create our unity javascriptLibrary file.

Save this to a file called `MetaMonitizationHandler.jslib` or any name you want but keep the extension, and put the file in any folder called Plugins in your project in unity.

Add this formatted javascript code to the file `MetaMonitizationHandler.jslib`,

```
var MetaMonitizationHandler =
{
    calcValue: function (data)
    {
        return (data.amount * (1 / Math.pow(10, data.assetScale)).toPrecision(data.assetScale)).toPrecision(data.assetScale);
    },

    Initialize: function ()
    {
        if (!typeof document.monetization)
        {
            console.log('document.monetization not found :(');
        }
        else
        {
            var info_div = document.querySelector('body > div > div.validator > div');
            var ilp_element = document.getElementById('ilpEnabled');
            var ilp_raw_init_el = document.getElementById('rawInit');
            var cur_pay_el = document.getElementById('currentPaymentAmt');
            var total_estimate_el = document.getElementById('totalEstimateAmt');
            var latest_json_el = document.getElementById('latestJson');

            document.monetization.addEventListener('monetizationstart', function (event)
            {
                info_div.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(63, 65, 68, 0.4)";
                ilp_element.innerHTML = "Interledger Enabled! (Meta-Tag)<br><br>:)  Thank You!<br>";
                ilp_raw_init_el.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(event.detail, null, 2).replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
            });

            document.monetization.addEventListener('monetizationprogress', function (event)
            {
                if (!typeof this.runningTotal)
                {
                    this.runningTotal = 0;
                }
                var monetizationAmount = parseFloat(calcValue(event.detail));
                this.runningTotal += monetizationAmount;
                document.monetization.lastEventPayload = event.detail;
                cur_pay_el.innerHTML = "Latest ILP Payment: $" + monetizationAmount;
                total_estimate_el.innerHTML = "Estimated ILP Total: $" + this.runningTotal.toPrecision(4);
                latest_json_el.innerHTML = "Latest ILP Payment Response: " + JSON.stringify(event.detail);

                coilScore = this.runningTotal.toPrecision(4);
                console.log("Type: " + typeof coilScore + " Total coilScore: " + coilScore);
                gameInstance.SendMessage('CoilValueTextObject', 'ReceiveCoilScore', coilScore);
            });
        }
    },
};
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, MetaMonitizationHandler);
```

Create a new C# script named `MonitizationManager.cs` or any name you see fit,
from this script we will initialize the monetization handler.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class MonitizationManager : MonoBehaviour
{
   [DllImport("__Internal")]
   static extern void Initialize(); // the function in the javascript which initializes the handles.

   private void Start()
   {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
      Initialize();
#endif
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was a really good find.  I changed it to public, changed the object name to ensure it was unique and Im still getting the same error.

`new object name = CoilValueTextObject`

`script function now public = public void ReceiveCoilScore(float newValue)`
`SendMessage: object CoilValueTextObject not found!`

Comment: What unity version are you using ? chances are if it's a new version, you need to use 'unityInstance' instead of 'gameInstance', cause unity renamed their javascript object to 'unityInstance' in new versions.

Comment: Im using 2019.2 and its showing in index.html as gameInstance.  Is it an issue to create the instance  again in my custom javascript (separate file) or should I try to call it gameInstance.SendMessage from JS using the index.html Instance?

Comment: By custom Javascript do you mean a .js file or .jslib file ?

Comment: .js  I edited original post as its easier to display up there than try to explain down here.

Comment: I edited the notes in the answer, let me know if it solves the problem.

Comment: I have remove the 2nd instantiation and displayed the full JS script.   

All its doing is collecting a value and creating a current sum and displaying other information.    Still receiving the same error that it cannot find the object.  `SendMessage: object CoilValueTextObject not found!`

Comment: I might know what the issue it.  It might be that the Main Camera needs to be able to see the object.  The UI is huge compared to the Camera view.  Checking on that,

Comment: Hi, no its not, the SendMessage function simply uses unity's Object.Find under the hood, which only checks all objects in the scene, regardless of their name, check my updated answer.

Comment: I will try this out and get back to you.  Did not see it until I had finished my posting above.

Comment: Where is the MonitizationManager.cs supposed to be attached to in Unity?  Not sure if I should attach it to object in question which is CoilValueTextObject.  
Thats the last part left for me to test this out.

Comment: Attach to any active gameobject in your scene, best way is to create an empty object call it MoniManager or w.e, and attach to it.

Comment: My answer above is the solution for my specific issue.  Thanks guys.